# Transforming data in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have data base like this:

```
table patient 
name , Id ---
table servise 
service_name 
servise_code----
tabal of fat 
price 
gross
```

The service name could be `pharmacy`, `consultation`, `ER`, `XRay`
when I do

```
select * 
from patient , service, fat
```

The result will be like this:

```
patien name     id       name service       code   price    groos 
====================================================================  
okon          01012454  consultion          2011   50       25
okon          01012454  pharmacy            9999   150      90 
oner          00110     condultion          4455   50       25
```

I have to do a report that will test where the service is pharmacy or consultation 
and there price and gross down of them like this

```
patien name     id        consultion       pharmacy      ER
                         price groos      price gross   price gross
==================================================================== 
okon          01012454   50    25           150  90     0      0   
oner          00110      50    25            0    0     0      0
```

How can I write the sql statement ??

Comment: Could you please edit table and Report structure so that it will be more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I will make some on the relations of the tables. If I am wrong I will fix it. But going on the information here I believe you will want a select something like this:

```
select p.name, p.id, f.price, f.gross 
    from patient p 
    left join servise s on p.id=s.pid 
    left join fat f on s.id=f.sid 
    where s.service_name='consultation' or s.service_name='pharmacy'
```

this supposes a foreign key relation between patient and servise (though maybe patient should have an sid instead?) and a foreign key relation between servise and fat.

Comment: unfortinatly i can't edit the relations between the tables; because it just a report and i dont want to make any changes .. please help me I was thinking in sub qury or do it like insert but how will know it have to return  0 when no pharmacy nor ER

Comment: What are the relations between your tables? From the information you have supplied I am not sure how your queries know how to relate anything to anything else.

Comment: maybe u will know the relationship from this query  i finally have idea it will test the code but the broplem in case syntax I need to say not = som valus..